# p5.js: keyIsPressed is not defined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to check for keyboard events within the `draw()` function, as I have to modify a global variable synchronously (therefore I can't simply put my code for keyboard events in a separate `keyTyped()` function). The problem is that when I use the variable `keyIsPressed` inside the `draw()` function, the following error appears:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: keyIsPressed is not defined
```

Below is my code:

```
var myp25;

var mazeDisplay = function(p) {
    p.setup = function() {
        var canvas = p.createCanvas(400, 400);
        p.background("#ff3056");
    }

    p.draw = function() {
        if (keyIsPressed === true) {
            console.log("key pressed.");
        }
    }
};

myp25 = new p5(mazeDisplay, "canvas2-wrapper")
```

But I am following the implementation of the `keyIsPressed` variable as shown in this link: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsPressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode), so every P5.js function and variable has to use your reference to the sketch. In your case this is your `p` variable.

```
if (p.keyIsPressed === true) {
```

> therefore I can't simply put my code for keyboard events in a separate keyTyped() function

You can, you just have to use the `p` variable.

```
p.keyTyped = function() {
  // whatever
}
```